# MailAddress C# Class replication in Snowflake

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, mailaddress

Migrating a stored procedure from SQL Server to Snowflake wherein on SQL Server side MailAddress C# function is being used to derive the `Address` from the `EmailAddress` column in the table. And also this is being used to check if the email is valid.

Essentially passing the column value to the `MailAddress` initialization command and within TRY/CATCH checking if its valid.

```
try
{
    MailAddress ma = new MailAddress(EmailAddress.ToString());
    Address = ma.Address;
    valid = true;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Address = null;
    valid = false;
}
```

When rewriting the procedure for Snowflake, obviously we don't have the same function in Snowflake. I understand we can create an external function now in C# but it will be a costly affair.

What I want to understand is since the base problem solved by the `MailAddress` class is to format the email address and check if it is following a set pattern. This is something can be done via REGEX in Snowflake.

Do we know what format checks `MailAddress` class perform on the value to try to replicate the same in Snowflake?

Comment: I wouldn't waste too much time validating email address, it's usually enough just to do a check on @ .existing. Even with a super validator, the email might fail anyway due to not existing, so just make sure it looks "good" enough and try to send it.

Comment: If you really want to replicate it, [the source is here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddress.cs,46)

Comment: If you want to see the futility of trying to validate email addresses, watch [Dylan Beattie's talk on email](https://youtu.be/mrGfahzt-4Q?si=sNLusuTLQt97ndUH)

Comment: It definitely does more then just things that can be replicated by a regex. The question is do you need that and do you need the side effect of MailAddress(s) behavior also?